# Retrieve property of <a> tag

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this:

```
<a class = "__cf_email__" 
  data-cfemail = "c2a3aca6b0a7a3eca1ada382a5afa3abaeeca1adaf"
  href = "http://www.cloudflare.com/email-protection">[email protected]</a>
```

and I need to get this string `c2a3aca6b0a7a3eca1ada382a5afa3abaeeca1adaf`. Any ideas? Don't know how I tried get the class but a can get the string

```
autor = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "__cf_email__"}, limit = 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes of `Tag`s are accessible via the `__getitem__` method. In other words, ["you can access a tag's attributes by treating the Tag object as though it were a dictionary."](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags)

```
>>> autor = soup.find("a", {"class": "__cf_email__"})
>>> print autor["data-cfemail"]
'c2a3aca6b0a7a3eca1ada382a5afa3abaeeca1adaf'
```

Comment: with this don't work

    <span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="c2a3aca6b0a7a3eca1ada382a5afa3abaeeca1adaf">[email protected]</span> there's any way to take the string from there?i tried your solution but don't work with span tag

Comment: Did you change `soup.find("a")` to `soup.find("span")`?

Comment: That would mean no such `span` tag was found. I have no problems finding the tag when I build a soup just from your included text. If you're having issues, ask a new question and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: i just found the error, the page change every time so i need to use 2 ways for get the string

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe mean to get the `data-cfemail` property of the `a`?